# How to disable Gmail read receipt nagging?

Tags: gmail

I have some coworkers and customers that send all of their e-mails with read receipts requested. Whenever I view one of these emails in Gmail and then try to leave, it asks me if I want to send a read receipt or not. I always click "No", but even if I view that message at a later date (such as trying to find an old email on a particular topic), Gmail will continue to nag me about sending read receipts.

Is there any way to tell Gmail that I never, ever, under any circumstance, *never* want to send a read receipt? This drives me absolutely insane. I must spend several hours over the course of the year just dismissing read receipt dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for Chrome:

[Read Receipt Decliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/read-receipt-decliner/nonmcdkdhgkljdlbkfdclcemmoenfbgb)

I just installed it and it works well. Still, I'm interested to hear if Gmail has an actual setting for this or not.

Answer (score 4):

Users of G Suite (not free Gmail) can now have their admin turn off the nagging:

[G Suite Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1383374)

### Set up read receipts

1. In your Google Admin console (at admin.google.com)...
   Go to Apps > G Suite > Gmail > User settings.
2. If you've created suborganizations in your Admin console, under Organizations at the left, select the organizational unit you want to configure settings for.  The Organizations section isn't available if no suborganizations have been created. For details, see "Configure advanced settings for Gmail".
3. In the Email read receipts section, specify the senders your users can return receipts to:

   - Do not allow read receipts to be sent: Disables requesting and returning read receipts.
   - Allow email read receipts to be sent to all addresses in my organization as well as the following email addresses: Restricts responses to addresses in your domains and any external addresses that you specify. Separate external email addresses with commas. You can enter up to 100 addresses; each address can have up to 256 characters. If you don't include any addresses, users will only be able to return receipts to other users in your domains.

     Check the box Prompt the user for each read receipt request to ask users each time they read an email if they want to send a receipt. Uncheck the box to automatically send read receipts.
   - Allow email read receipts to be sent to any email address: Allows read receipts to be requested and returned from email addresses inside and outside your organization. Users are always prompted to send a receipt.
4. At the bottom, click Save.

It might take up to an hour for your changes to apply to individual user accounts. You can track prior changes in the Admin console audit log.