# How come there's no option to send a Read Receipt from a G Suite account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

[Google's FAQ](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651) clearly states:

> This feature is only available if you use Gmail for work or school set
>   up by an administrator. If you use a gmail.com account, read receipts
>   won’t work.

Alas, using Gmail for work, I get no such option.

How is it possible? Is Google's FAQ untrue? Did they remove the feature? Alternatively, is it only for certain G Suite editions, which their FAQ fails to mention?

[image: No Read Receipt in Gmail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what Google's FAQ fails to mention is that an admin can simply disable this feature.

See [How to disable Gmail read receipt nagging?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50446/how-to-disable-gmail-read-receipt-nagging)